# How to use the speech recognition module in linux

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am trying to use speechrecognition on linux.
In windows, it works fine but in linux it throws this error:

```
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
```

Here is the code:

```
def takecom():
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("listening....")
        r.pause_threshold=1
        audio=r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("recognizing.....")
        query=r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
        print(f"user: {query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        # print(e)
        print("say that again please....")
        return "None"
    return query
```